# React Quill in nextJS has a duplicate tab

Tags: reactjs, next.js, quill

I have react-quill installed in my nextjs project
The code is work but its have a bug where the tab is doubled
[image: bug]

i was so confused

```
import { useState } from "react";
    import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
    const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });
    import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
    
    function App() {
      const [value, setValue] = useState("");
      const modules = {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: "1" }, { header: "2" }, { font: [] }],
          [{ size: [] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
          [
            { list: "ordered" },
            { list: "bullet" },
            { indent: "-1" },
            { indent: "+1" },
          ],
          ["link", "image", "video"],
          ["clean"],
        ],
        clipboard: {
          matchVisual: false,
        },
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <ReactQuill
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
            theme='snow'
            modules={modules}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

can someone help to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. What version of `react-quill` are you using? Can you provide a codesandbox (or similar) showing the issue?

Comment: also having this issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using nextjs in **strict** mode please remove the strict mode true option and it will working properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be a PR to fix this issue but until then a workaround is to
add to the global.css

```
.quill > .ql-toolbar:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and it will fix